# How to calculate accuracy of each feature

Tags: machine-learning, classification, accuracy

I read [some paper](http://www2013.org/proceedings/p331.pdf) (* about predicting user retention in StumbledUpon) and saw the authors provide a list of features with accuracy of each feature with the following explanation:

> [image]
>   As decision trees use information
>   gain to find the best feature, we instead use decision
>   trees with single features and report their accuracies on
>   the decision tree classification for retained and non-retained
>   URLs. Table 2 shows the ranking based on chi-square measure
>   and the decision tree accuracy on individual features.

I am confused about how they can do it. I can just imagine using chi-squared to make a rank and to know the most important features (features evaluation), but in this case I don't know how to calculate the accuracy of each feature.
Thank you.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you please edit your answer to make it explicit exactly what you're asking please?

Comment: @Glen_b thank you for comment, I already add a figure in my question, the problem is how they can calculate the accuracy for each feature?

Comment: A paper you don't cite gave results you don't understand. Sorry, but this is very unclear. Even if you gave the reference, we would still have to wade through it to understand the question.

Comment: @NickCox Actually i got this paper from www conference 2013 http://www2013.org/proceedings/p331.pdf , they didnt explain how to get that value (accuracy). But for the Chi-Square i know how to measure it.

Comment: I'd write to the authors. There are email addresses. You're new here, but please try a little role reversal: People who answer questions do so for various reasons, including the question being interesting and their wanting to help others. But your question is still: Please read through a densely written 11 page paper and tell me what the authors are doing. Would you do that for someone else? Questions work well here when they can be understood by reading what the OP writes, in at most a few minutes. Your question doesn't qualify in my view.

Comment: Thank you @NickCox for editing my question and sorry for my english

Comment: I'd also advise asking one of the authors via email (and then answering your own question here). There seems to be more than one way to measure predictive accuracy in classification. One way is likely standard in this particular application area (so someone here may well be able to give a very educated guess), but the way to be sure is to ask them what they did. It's what I'd do if I had this question - just ask the authors what the definition of accuracy was in Table 2. If you do that, take some time over composing your question - make it as clear and concise as you can (they're likely busy).

Comment: @user46543: your English is pretty good actually. Hopefully I've found the important bits of the paper that will help others explain the method; I don't know enough about decision trees to say whether this is enough to go on.

Comment: @Glen_b I already ask to the authors but he didn't answer it so i post in here, and thank you for your comment